# Expand card in horizontal flat list in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal list(paging enabled) required in my react-native app and i want to expand/collapse that card when user swipe up/ down. In collapsed position, card has less width after expand width of card would increase. I want to do this animation using native
driver.

Please let me know if anyone have any solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the SwipeGestureHandler/PanGestureHandler of [react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/) to handle the swiping or panning of cards.

Then you can use the [Animated](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated) of react-native to handle the animation.